# Ruby watir webdriver: how to keep scrolling through lazy loading

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to capture all the links on a page, unfortunately the page does lazy loading and I miss out on all the links unless I scroll to the absolute bottom.

How do I write code for this? I'm currently using watir-scroll. I do not know beforehand how many times I'll need to scroll (scroll till I can't, basically).

```
      browser.scroll.to :bottom
```

Is what I'm using ATM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to determine the last link on a page with lazy loaded but limited list of options you can do something along the lines of:

```
loop do
  link_number = browser.links.size
  browser.scroll.to :bottom
  break if browser.links.size == link_number
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by limited? Does the browser know this last_location in advance?     
Edit: Just to be clear, by lazy loading I understand that the more you scroll, the more of the page's content is visible and not all of this is loaded initially, correct?

Comment: I guess there is no true "infinite" list; I'm just saying the code I'm providing is an infinite loop if it never reaches a "bottom"

Comment: and yes, lazy loaded means that there are additional javascript calls that add information to the DOM that was not there previously. The last location is for what is presently in the DOM. As things get added, the location will change, so when nothing else is added, the location returned will be the same.

Comment: It doesn't work, it only scrolls once. Not to the bottom. How does browser.links.last work?

Comment: browser.links is a collection of all link elements in the DOM. Last is the last one of those. :)

Comment: Try the updated code. I was making it more complicated than it needed.

Comment: It still seems to scroll only once. I tried scrolling down a page I knew had more links and it only retrieved the first iteration.       
eg, I'm scrolling down https://www.facebook.com/search/pages/?q=facebook and the last link I get is facebookarabia, which is only one 'scroll' down towards the bottom.

Comment: instead of scrolling with browser.scroll.to :bottom, try browser.links.last.wd.location_once_scrolled_into_view Maybe the issue is with p0deje's javascript implementation of scroll.

Comment: Oh, you need to put a sleep in there to wait for the javascript call to return with additional content.

Comment: How long should the sleep be? is there a standard time or...more of a play around thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99146/discussion-between-titusfortner-and-tvishwa107).